# Opencv Create Trackbar

Tags: python, opencv, trackbar

When I run this code :

```
def nothing(x):
    pass

cv.createTrackbar(‘R’, ‘image’, 0,255,nothing)
```

I get this error:
Using ‘value’ pointer is unsafe and deprecated. Use NULL as value pointer. To fetch trackbar value setup callback.

I couldn’t find what to do.

Comment: the pass is not indented within the nothing(x) function. Did you you try it with having it indented? Please also let us know the error type as well.

Comment: I've tried many different ways, including the one you asked me to try..

Comment: error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-u4kjpz2z\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:2359: error: (-27:Null pointer) NULL window: 'image' in function 'icvCreateTrackbar'



[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-u4kjpz2z\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp (704) cv::createTrackbar UI/Trackbar(R@image): Using 'value' pointer is unsafe and deprecated. Use NULL as value pointer. To fetch trackbar value setup callback.

Comment: Did you try to return None instead of pass?

Comment: Yes I try this :cv.createTrackbar('R', 'image', 0,255,None) I get this error :on_change must be callable

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you should  check `return some_value` inside `def nothing()`, not `createTrackbar(..., None)`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show minimal working code which makes problem so I can only guess.

You have to create window `"image"` before you use `createTrackbar()`

```
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.createTrackbar('R', 'image', 0, 255, function)
```

---

Minimal working example:

```
import cv2

# --- functions ---

def function(value):
    print(value)

    new_img = img.copy()
    new_img[:,:,2] = value

    cv2.imshow('image', new_img)

# --- main ---
    
img = cv2.imread('lenna.png')

cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.createTrackbar('R', 'image', 0, 255, function)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

**EDIT:**

More complex example with three trackbars which use the same function but with different index.

```
import cv2

# --- functions ---

def function(index, value):
    percent = (value/100)
    #print(index, value, percent)

    img[:,:,index] = original_img[:,:,index] * percent

    cv2.imshow('image', img)
   
# --- main ---
 
img = cv2.imread('lenna.png')

original_img = img.copy()

cv2.namedWindow('image')

cv2.createTrackbar('R (%)', 'image', 100, 100, lambda value:function(2, value))
cv2.createTrackbar('G (%)', 'image', 100, 100, lambda value:function(1, value))
cv2.createTrackbar('B (%)', 'image', 100, 100, lambda value:function(0, value))

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Image [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) from Wikipedia

---

**EDIT:**

Your problem is that you use two names for window - `img` and `image` - but you should use the same name in `namedWindow()`, `createTrackbar()`, `getTrackbarPos()`, `imshow()`

BTW: If you create trackbar with `'0 : OFF \n1 : ON'` then you have to use it aslo to get value `s = cv.getTrackbarPos(switch, 'image')`

**EDIT:**

It seems you have the same code as in [demo](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_trackbar/py_trackbar.html#code-demo) in documentation and `demo` uses `"image"` in all commands. `demo` also uses `cv.getTrackbarPos(switch, ...)`

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def nothing(x): 
    pass

img = np.array ((512,512,3), np.uint8) 
cv.namedWindow("image") 

cv.createTrackbar('R', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv.createTrackbar('G', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv.createTrackbar('B', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)

switch = '0 : OFF \n1 : ON'
cv.createTrackbar(switch, 'image', 1, 1, nothing)

while True:
    cv.imshow('image', img)
    
    key = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    
    if key == 27:
        break
    
    r = cv.getTrackbarPos('R', 'image')
    g = cv.getTrackbarPos('G', 'image')
    b = cv.getTrackbarPos('B', 'image')
    s = cv.getTrackbarPos(switch, 'image')
    
    if s == 0:
        img[:] = 0 
        # reset trackbars
        #cv.setTrackbarPos('R', 'image', 0)
        #cv.setTrackbarPos('G', 'image', 0)
        #cv.setTrackbarPos('B', 'image', 0)
    else:
        img[:] = [b,g,r]
        
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

The same with code in `nothing` so it is executed only when you change value in any trackbar.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# --- functions ---

def nothing(value): 
    r = cv.getTrackbarPos('R', 'image')
    g = cv.getTrackbarPos('G', 'image')
    b = cv.getTrackbarPos('B', 'image')
    s = cv.getTrackbarPos(switch, 'image')

    if s == 0:
        img[:] = 0
        # reset trackbars
        #cv.setTrackbarPos('R', 'image', 0)
        #cv.setTrackbarPos('G', 'image', 0)
        #cv.setTrackbarPos('B', 'image', 0)
    else:
        img[:] = [b,g,r]
        
# --- main ---

img = np.array ((512,512,3), np.uint8)

cv.namedWindow("image") 

cv.createTrackbar('R', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv.createTrackbar('G', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv.createTrackbar('B', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)

switch = '0 : OFF \n1 : ON'
cv.createTrackbar(switch, 'image', 1, 1, nothing)

while True:
    cv.imshow('image', img)
    
    key = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    
    if key == 27:
        break
    
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: try both solutions i still get same error, ı added all the code

Comment: I saw your code and all your problem is that you use wrong names for windows. First you create window with name `img` but later you assign trackbars to window with name `image`, and later you display window with name `img`. You have to use the same name - `img` or `image` in all commands: `namedWindow`, `createTrackbar`, `getTrackbarPos`, `imshow`

Comment: BTW: you have to use `'0 : OFF \n1 : ON'` instead of `S` in `s = cv.getTrackbarPos('0 : OFF \n1 : ON', 'image')`

Comment: It seems like you have the same code as in [demo](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_trackbar/py_trackbar.html#code-demo) and `demo` uses `image` in all commands. And `demo` also use `cv.getTrackbarPos(switch, ...)`

Comment: thanks for the example in the 1st edit. What does  `original_img[:,:,index] * percent` do? it just returns value between 0 and the maximum value **in** array (which could be less than 255), right?

Comment: notice further the `cv`-arithmetic is different from that of `np` (saturated vs modulo) and its useful to avoid exceeding the "black"  threshold value, [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html)